# How to update custom property of docx file using php

Tags: php

I want to read docx file and I want to change parts of a word document (*.docx). I already convert docx into zip. I want to add new custom properties (docProps/custom.xml) in docx file. When I create new docx file. I able to add custom property via php word. But, I want to read docx file and update custom property. It's not possible using phpword.

When I convert docx into zip and open docpProps/custom.xml. By default it provided xml content as provided below:

Current xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties"
    xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
    <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="1" name="Property Id">
        <vt:lpwstr>121</vt:lpwstr>
    </property>
</Properties>
```

I want to add new properties and save into zip file as provided below

Updated content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties"
    xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
    <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="1" name="Property Id">
        <vt:lpwstr>121</vt:lpwstr>
    </property>
    <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="Description">
        <vt:lpwstr>Lorem ipsum</vt:lpwstr>
    </property>
    <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="User Id">
        <vt:lpwstr>12</vt:lpwstr>
    </property>
</Properties>
```

My php code:

```
        $zip = new \ZipArchive;

        // Open this Zip File
        if ($zip->open('helloWorld.docx') == true) {
            // Get custom xml content
            $xmlContent = $zip->getFromName('docProps/custom.xml');

            // I want to update docProps/custom.xml file

            $zip->close();
        }
```

How is this possible anyone know please reply or give me example script.

Comment: Have you looked at the phpOffice/phpWord library?

Comment: Yes, It's not possible via phpword.

Comment: Can you clarify what custom properties you're looking to add? Additionally, what have you tried so far? As it's currently written, this question needs more details.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I have added more details in question

Comment: Thats not enough details. Show us your php code that you have already and that fails. We help you _debug_ your code. We wont write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I able to update custom.xml using below code:

```
    $zip = new \ZipArchive;

    // Open this Zip File
    if ($zip->open('helloWorld.docx') == true) {
        // Get custom xml content
        $xmlContent = $zip->getFromName('docProps/custom.xml');

        // Update docPros/custom.xml content
        $updatedXmlContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <Properties
            xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties"
            xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
            <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="Id">
                <vt:lpwstr>121</vt:lpwstr>
            </property>
            <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="Notes">
                <vt:lpwstr>Lorem ipsum</vt:lpwstr>
            </property>
            <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="4" name="User">
                <vt:lpwstr>12</vt:lpwstr>
            </property>
        </Properties>';

        //Replace the content with the new content created above.
        $zip->addFromString('docProps/custom.xml', $updatedXmlContent);
        $zip->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is just XML. Use SimpleXML to modify the file

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php